# PHP Hiding a button if data exist

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to Hide the button if "name" is empty
no error show but the button is still showing I tried adding css to it but the button still show

```
 <table style="width:100%" border="1px">
<tr align="center">
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Image</th>
  <th>PDF</th>
  <th>Grade</th>
  <th>Date</th>
</tr>
  
<?php

foreach ($records as $value) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  echo '<tr align="center">';
  echo "<td>" . $value['name'] . "</td>";

if ($value['name']  != ''){
echo "<td> <a  class='design' style='display:none;' href='".$value['img_name']."'>Download image</a></td>";
}else{
    echo "<td> <a  class='design' href='".$value['img_name']."'>Download image</a></td>";
}

  echo "<td><a class='cert' href='".$value['pdf_name']."' download>Download PDF</a></td>";
  echo "<td>". $value['score']."</td>";
  echo "<td>". $value['date']."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Your showing button has attribute "hidden" or "download" ?

Comment: Is there any reason that you are still outputting a button if there is no value? Unless the button is required, it's better to have PHP not output anything.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the class `hide` to the first if condition and add `display: none` to that class

**HTML:**

```
if ($value['name']  != ''){
    echo "<td> <a  class='design hide' href='".$value['img_name']."'>Download image</a></td>";
}else{
    echo "<td> <a  class='design' href='".$value['img_name']."'>Download image</a></td>";
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.hide { display: none; }
```

Comment: That means that you end up in the second if condition.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a function called `empty`, which can be used to determine if a variable is empty or not.

For your situation, I don't see why you would want PHP to output a button if it's simply going to be hidden by CSS afterwards.

In PHP, you could use the empty function like this:

```
<?php
$var4you = "";

if (!empty($var4you)) {
    //Display only when there is a value
}
?>
```

For you to you this within your code, you'd likely want to do this:

```
<?php
if (!empty($value['name'])) {
    echo "<td> <a  class='design' href='".$value['img_name']."'>Download image</a></td>";
}
?>
```

You can learn more about using the `empty` function in PHP in the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php